# VueJS - Assigning value to this.property within callback

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

How can I force

> this.json = reader.result;

to assign value to this.json properly in given scope?

Because the value is there, but it is not assigned.

```
<div id="app" >
    <label class="text-reader"><input type="file" v-on:change="getFile($event)"></label>
    {{ json }} // it's being set to "test" from getFile function.
</div>
```

Here's VueJS Code

---

```
new Vue
({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        json: {}
    },
    methods:
    {
        getFile: function(ev) 
        {
            this.json = "test";

            var file = ev.target.files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function(e) 
            {
                this.json = reader.result;
                console.log(this.json);  // displays content properly
            }

            reader.readAsText(file);     
        }
    }
});
```

---

What I've been trying so far is just adding some kind of handler

```
getFile: function(ev) 
{
    var file = ev.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(e) 
    {
        this.callBackHandler(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
},
callBackHandler: function(val)
{
    console.log(val);
    this.json = val;
}
```

It yells:

> TypeError: this.callBackHandler is not a function

---

Also using callBackHandler as a param.

```
<label class="text-reader"><input type="file" v-on:change="getFile($event, callBackHandler())"></label>

getFile: function(ev, handler) 
{
    var file = ev.target.files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(handler) 
    {
        handler(reader.result);
    }

    reader.readAsText(file);
},
callBackHandler: function(val)
{
    console.log(val);
    this.json = val;
}
```

Comment: Use arrow function or bind `this` to your reader.onload function; or make it that way:  declare let self = this; in the getFile method and then use 
self.callBackHandler() inside reader.onload

Comment: @ElDanielo Please write it as an answer, it worked. reader.onload = (x => 
            {
                this.callBackHandler(reader.result);
            });

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getFile function should look like this:

```
getFile: function(ev, handler) {
        var file = ev.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = (e => {
            this.callBackHandler(reader.result);
        }) 
}
```

or

```
getFile: function(ev, handler) {
        var file = ev.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        var self = this;
        reader.onload = function(e){
            self.callBackHandler(reader.result);
        } 
}
```

or

```
getFile: function(ev, handler) {
        var file = ev.target.files[0];
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e){
            this.callBackHandler(reader.result);
        }.bind(this) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
v-on:change="getFile($event)"

(...)

reader.onload = (x => 
{
    this.callBackHandler(reader.result);
});
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it lacks explanation. Please consider adding text to explain what it does, and why it answers the question posed.